# ASP.Net GridView templateField

Tags: gridview, templatefield

**Summary:**

I want to to create a `templateField` resulting from a database after calling `gridview.databind` to have it function as a linkbutton doing something when pressing it.

In other words, I want to bind a `templateField` with data at runtime.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" OnClick="lclick">Buy</asp:LinkButton>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>


protected void lclick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // your function
}
```

Comment: Ok; but I'm still need to know to dynamically add bind data to this template field.